# Horizontal Swipe Slideshow?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, gsap

recently I've been seeing a trend of swipe galleries and I was wondering what the common way to build them is? I know Slick Slider allows swiping but I'm pretty sure none of these sites are using a standard slideshow plugin.

Maybe some using Canvas? Greensock? Examples below:

https://collagecrafting.com/

http://artempivovarov.com/photo-gallery

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be using CSS animations, which also would be one of the best/easiest ways for you to do it. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Basically, all they're doing is changing the position of it. One example animation that would do a slide effect is the following:

```
.slideLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    animation-name: slideLeft;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes slideLeft {
    from {
        left: 25%;
    }
    to {
        left: 0%;
    }
}
```